# Volume of a section of a sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, spherical-coordinates

A section of a sphere is described by $0 ≤  ≤ 2$, $0 ≤  ≤ 90°$, $30° ≤  ≤ 90°$.

Now, just by using simple symmetry, I can see that the volume of this section will be less than 1/8th of the volume of a sphere with radius 2.

> Volume of the section < (Volume of the sphere of radius $2$) $/$ $8$

Volume of a sphere of radius $2$ is $33.51$ according to $4/3 \pi r^3$. I solved it using differential method but my answer is more than $1/8$th of the volume. What is wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the first step we are integrating

$$\int_0^2 r^2 dr=\frac13 [r^3]_0^2=\frac83$$

Comment: At first, I did the same thing. But then I changed it  because I thought $r$ is constant.

Comment: @Goodfellow Recall that we are evaluating a volume and $r$ varies form $0$ to $2$, oherwise we stay on the surface.

Comment: Isn't changing r in the limit of the integral is enough?

Comment: @Goodfellow Think to a 2D integral for the area of an unitary circle $$\int_0^{2\pi} \,d\theta \int_0^1 r\,dr$$ How do you calculate it?

Comment: okay, now I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @Goodfellow Well done, you are welcome! Bye